# Are the eigenvalues of the sum of two positive definite matrices increased?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ (symmetric) positive definite matrices, and denote the $k$th smallest eigenvalue of a general $n \times n$ matrix by $\lambda_k(X)$, $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ so that $$\lambda_1(X) \leq \lambda_2(X) \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n(X).$$ I guess the following relation holds:
$$\lambda_k(A + B) > \max\{\lambda_k(A), \lambda_k(B)\}, \; k = 1, 2, \ldots, n.$$

This looks intuitive but I have difficulty to prove it, any hints?

Comment: How do you order eigenvalues?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I am trying to say any eigenvalue of the sum should be greater than the corresponding ones. To be more precise, I will edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For symmetric matrices you have the [Courant-Fischer min-max Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem):
$$\lambda_k(A) =  \min \{ \max \{ R_A(x) \mid x \in U \text{ and } x \neq 0 \} \mid \dim(U)=k \}$$
with
$$R_A(x) = \frac{(Ax, x)}{(x,x)}.$$
Now, your assertion follows easily, since $R_{A+B}(x) > \max\{R_A(x), R_B(x)\}$.

This theorem is also helpful to prove other nice properties of the eigenvalues of **symmetric** matrices. For example:
\begin{equation*}
 \lambda_k(A) + \lambda_1(B) \le \lambda_k(A+B) \le \lambda_k(A) + \lambda_n(B)
\end{equation*}
This shows the continuous dependence of the Eigenvalues on the entries of the matrix, and also your assertion.

Comment: Does this result also hold for sum of semi definite positive matrices? (changing the > for ≥ )

Comment: Yes and it's the same proof.

Comment: @grew : your last equation is not inline with the question. OP is considering $\lambda_n$ as the lowest eigen value and $\lambda_1$ as highest. But you seem to consider the other way.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju You are right! Now the question has been edited, so that question and answer share the same notation.

Comment: Good answer! Does it still hold when we have a sum of positive semidefinite and negative semidefinite matrices? Say, $A$ is psd and $B$ is nsd, then does it hold that $$\lambda_n(A+B)\le \lambda_n(A)+\lambda_n(B)$$

Comment: @user777: Yes, this formula only needs the symmetry of $A$ and $B$.