# Eigenvalues of the sum of a positive and a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ respectively a positive and a positive semi-definite matrix. Is it possible to establish an upper bound for the minimum eigenvalue of the sum?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1622770/43949) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $\lambda_1(A)\geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n(A)$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$.  [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory) gives us the bound
$$
\lambda_n(A + B) \leq \lambda_i(A) + \lambda_{n+1-i}(B) \quad i = 1,\dots,n.
$$
In particular, we can see that if $B$ has rank $r$, then taking $i = n-r$ gives us
$$
\lambda_n(A + B) \leq \lambda_{n-r}(A).
$$