# characteristic summation of a positive definite matrix and a covariance matrix of a non-square matrix with positive elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, symmetric-matrices

I have tow matrices $A_{n \times n}$ and $B_{n \times m}$ which $m<n$. $A_{n \times n}$ is a diagonal positive definite and $B_{n \times m}$ is a non-square matrix with positive or zero elements.
 I want to find that If matrix $C_{n \times n}$ is semi-positive definite or not:
$C_n = A_{n \times n} + B_{n \times m}B_{n \times m}^T$
as we know, $B_{n \times m}B_{n \times m}^T$ is covarian matrix of matrix $B_{n \times m}$ and is symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the sum of positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite, $A_{n \times n}$ is positive semidefinite, and $B_{n \times m}B^\text{T}_{n \times m}$ is too since for all $x$ we have
$$
x^\text{T} B_{n \times m} B^\text{T}_{n \times m} x
= (B^\text{T}_{n \times m} x)^\text{T} B^\text{T}_{n \times m} x
= \lVert B^\text{T}_{n \times m} x \rVert^2 \geq 0.
$$
So, the matrix $C_{n\times n}$ is always positive semidefinite, too.

Comment: can you explain more about equation that you have written or give me a keyword to I read more? can you give me a textbook title about it?

Comment: I am just checking the definition of positive definiteness, and then using the fact that the transpose of a real matrix is its adjoint: what is your definition of positive definiteness?

Comment: Actually, I have rewritten my calculation: does that make more sense to you now?

Comment: Got it!!
Thank you.

Comment: Can it be proved that eigenvalues of matrix C are larger or equal that matrix A? I want to know the effect of matrix BB' on matrix A.

Comment: In general we can e.g. say that $\lambda_1(A + B B^\text{T}) \geq \max(\lambda_1(A),\lambda_1(B B^\text{T}))$. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622747/are-the-eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-two-positive-definite-matrices-increased/1622770 for the min-max principle, from which other bounds can be obtained.

Comment: Very good! thank you