# Eigenvalue inequalities from Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a set of $N$ Hermitian matrices all with the same dimensions, $\{ K_i\}$, for which $\sum_{j=1}^N K_j^2$ commutes with each $K_i$, and the commutator of $K_i$ and $K_j$ is full rank for all $i$ and $j$.

Then is the largest eigenvalue of $\sum_{j=1}^N K_j^2$ strictly greater than the largest eigenvalues of all of the individual $K_i^2$?

---

Note that the fact that the largest eigenvalue of  $\sum_{j=1}^N K_j^2$ is greater than **or equal** to the largest eigenvalue of all the individual $K_i^2$ follows from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622770).

As an aside, my motivation for this question comes from physics, which I detailed in a similar [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/698178/uncertainty-principle-manifesting-in-jj1-vs-j2) on Physics Stack Exchange. As noted in that question, there are cases in physics textbooks when the fact that $\sum_{j=1}^N K_j^2$ has a strictly greater maximum eigenvalue than any of the $K_i^2$ is imputed to the non-commutation of the $K_i$ and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.

However, that is not obviously the case, and in fact, Michael Seifert found a [counterexample](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/698278) for the case where the commutators of $K_i$ and $K_j$ did not need to be full rank. With my additional constraint of full-rank commutators, I feel the question is more appropriate for MSE, since it's not a constraint that appears very naturally in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $u$ be a unit eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $K_1^2$. Since $K_1$ is Hermitian, it has an eigenvalue $\mu\in\left\{\sqrt{\lambda_\max(K_1^2)},\,-\sqrt{\lambda_\max(K_1^2)}\right\}$. For any $j>1$, since $[K_1,K_j]$ has full rank, $0\ne[K_1,K_j]u=(K_1-\mu I)K_ju$. Therefore $K_ju$ is nonzero and
$$
\lambda_\max\left(\sum_iK_i^2\right)
\ge\left\langle u,\,\sum_iK_i^2u\right\rangle
=\lambda_\max(K_1^2)+\sum_{j>1}\left\langle K_ju,\,K_ju\right\rangle
>\lambda_\max(K_1^2).
$$